# How to load X509Certificate2 from a DER Certificate with Private Key?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509, x509certificate2, der

When using PEM format for both certificate and its private key, it is easy to load them into .NET program by calling:

```cs
X509Certificate2 Certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPemFile(SslCertificate, SslPrivateKey);
```

It returns a correct object, suitable for SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer method, and other encrypting stuff as well. But I'm have only DER-formatted files, and loading of them results in a exception:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The certificate
> contents do not contain a PEM with a CERTIFICATE label, or the content
> is malformed.

Attempt to load via `Certificate = new X509Certificate2(SslCertificate)` gives a X509Certificate2 object without Private Key, making it useless for SslStream.

How to properly load DER files (a certificate and a private key) as X509Certificate2 object in C#?

Comment: I do not write much x.509 code in C#. However, a few important concepts. If you have the private key you have everything. The public key certificate is used to load the public key. The private key already contains the public key.

Comment: I'm asked how to use them if they're in DER format (because C# prefers PEM). But currently I'm found how to get them in PEM format, and the question is no longer actual.